# How to overcome circular imports using refrences or functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am working on an existing project and for the sake of not breaking the functionality of the entire application, restructuring the application is not allowed, causing me to run into some very long circular import issues.

I wanted to know whether there was a solution available like it is for type checking which allows me to bypass the circular import issue for other things like callables or variables.

For example:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from somemodule import A # This is the line causing import issue.

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from somemodule import A # Solution for type checking.

def func() -> 'A': # This works
    return 'A'(a=1, b=1) # But what can I do for this ?
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

The error that I get is along the lines

```
  File "SomePath", line 5, in <module>
    from somemodule import A
  File "SomeOtherPath", line 6, in <module>
    from nrelatedmodule2 import get_something
  File "SomePath", line 20, in <module>
    from relatedmodule1 import get_another_thing
  File "SomeOtherPath", line 3, in <module>
    from somemodule import A
```

Comment: What is the name of you file.

Comment: what if you import A inside the function?

Comment: @SharimIqbal, Which file name ? the current module or the one being imported.

Comment: @najeem, That is a good suggestion but there are lots of functions, I don't want to be importing into all of them.

Comment: @SAK current running file name. The second thing is what error you got.

Comment: @SAK is there a `somemodule` file.

Comment: @SharimIqbal, I am not at liberty to share the actual info because it is company property, but something like user_model, and the error I have posted in the question and yes there is a somemodule file with name something like 'social_provider'

Comment: circular import is the consequence of a bad project structure if you don't troubleshoot, this will bring chaos to the project, and your project loses the ability to extend, or the program become so slow

Comment: I agree to the above comment. If you have reached a point where you end up with circular imports, it's probably time to fix that before you move further. Else your life is going to be hard hence forth. Also, it's going to be hard to help you with this problem here unless we see the entire code and how the various imports work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check whether a name (such as `A`) is defined :

```py
'A' in globals()
```

Using this you should be able to import A if and only if some other name is undefined :

```py
if not module in globals():
    import A
```

Or import `A` unless it is already imported :

```py
if not A in globals():
    import A
```

Comment: Although it's likely these kinds of tricks should belong in an `__init__.py` ; is there no such `__init__.py` file to import from ?